# Is this really a peevish question?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic

Is the following question [On the verb 'peruse'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/234671/on-the-verb-peruse) peevish?

A question about a verb  that has two distinct opposite meanings. Its etymologic evolution;  the use of the two opposite meanings( does one meaning usage prevail on the other);  what do  natives first think when they read or use it (reading carefully or skimming);  way to avoid to misuse it and risk misunderstandings etc...Isn't all this English Usage??

Comment: Whether it actually is a peeve or not, with respect to any existing or inferred question in there, what would an answer look like? "Why did this happen? Because (see chapter on semantic drift)"

Comment: I read it as question 'How come there's two meanings that seem to contradict each other' with an added 'peeve' of 'That's plain stupid'. I would vote to reopen but it'll only be closed as a duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116016/does-the-word-peruse-have-a-single-meaning-of-attentive-reading-or-double so it seems hardly worth it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, all that is English usage. Sadly, exactly none of that is actually *in* the question. Instead, it reads, "How come then that they've made it to the top of a page in the virtual Merriam Webster Dictionary? It doesn't make any sense to me. Jeez! "

I shall not today attempt further to define the kinds of material I understand to be embraced within the shorthand description *peeving*, and perhaps I could never succeed in intelligibly doing so. But I know it when I see it, and this question in its current form is precisely that.

The OP is free to edit it into shape, though. *You* are free to edit it into shape, if you want the OP to get credit for your work.

Comment: It is a pity that you didn't consider improving it before closing! As for myself, my answer implies the fact I think it is a valid question. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Josh61 It's not closed, it's on hold ready to be improved. You can do that, and then vote to re-open.

Comment: I've discovered the question—it was under our nose all the time—and reworded it as: "Why did the more modern-day definition make it to the top of a page in the Merriam Webster Dictionary?" I've also substituted the "peevish" expressions. I think the OP is more than acceptable, and a better question than 70% of the questions that have been posted recently.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I appreciate your efforts to clean up the question, it's very clearly much less of a peeve now, but I don't see how it's any more answerable.  "Why did the editor choose to list these two definitions, in this order" seems a question that only the editor can give a satisfactory explanation for.

Comment: The reason for putting it on hold was that it was a rant disguised as a question. Is the question now acceptable and fair? Is the question clear now? Is the question now useful for future visitors? Can the question be answered? I believe it is.

Comment: But it could be closed as a duplicate... following Frank's observation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I will let others decide its fate, but as it stands, if it were open I would still vote to close it as Off-Topic Due To Being A Question About The Dictionary-Editing Process, Not About English.

Comment: @Hellion Yep, that's why I VTC originally - there was no actual, on-topic question anywhere in the question body. That hasn't changed.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The reason for putting it on hold was that the only actual question it contained was "how come this definition is on this website?" I commented to try and get the asker to provide an actual question about the English language, but so far that hasn't happened. The problem with the rant wasn't that it was ranty, but that there was no actual question substance. You did a good job of making it less inflammatory, but unfortunately your edit didn't do anything to bring it back on topic.

Comment: Incidentally and for what it's worth, most of the answers don't actually answer the question that is being asked.

Comment: @starsplusplus  The exact question was: *"How come then that they've made it to the top of a page"*  I think my answer attempts to address that point. If The OP (wherever he is) disagrees with my interpretation, he can always improve his own post. :)

Comment: Yes, I think your answer is the only one that does attempt to answer that. All the other answers answer different questions.